# Code Mirror not rendering correctly on Heroku Rails 6 app

Tags: javascript, ruby, webpack, codemirror, ruby-on-rails-6

I recently added the code mirror editor to my rails 6 app. I was able to get everything working fine on my local environment (ubuntu 18.04), but when I deploy the app to heroku the code mirror editor renders the actual text editing area far below the div. It also seems to be filling it with x's. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1oiq.png) is a screenshot of it. The x's near the top are actually part of the top editor not shown, and the lower x's are part of the main editor in the picture.

Here is my application.js file:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import { autocompleteExport } from '../custom/autocomplete';
import { initialize } from '../custom/editor';
import { formatToc } from '../custom/page_display';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", autocompleteExport.categories)
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", autocompleteExport.search)
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", autocompleteExport.admins)
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", initialize)
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", formatToc)
```

and here is the editor file that initializes the editors:

```
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.js'
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
import 'codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown.js'

function initialize(){
    let textArea = document.getElementById('page_edit_content')
    let editor = document.getElementById('content-editor')

    if(textArea && !editor){
        var contentEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
                                                    lineWrapping: true,
                                                    mode: "markdown",
                                                });

        contentEditor.display.wrapper.id = "content-editor"
    }

    textArea = null
    editor = null

    textArea = document.getElementById('page_edit_summary')
    editor = document.getElementById("summary-editor")

    if(textArea && !editor){
        var contentEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
            lineWrapping: true,
            mode: "markdown",
        });

        contentEditor.display.wrapper.id = "summary-editor"
    }

    textArea = null
    editor = null

    textArea = document.getElementById('page_content')
    editor = document.getElementById("new-content-editor")

    if(textArea && !editor){
        var contentEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
            lineWrapping: true,
            mode: "markdown",
        });

        contentEditor.display.wrapper.id = "new-content-editor"
    }

    textArea = null
    editor = null

    textArea = document.getElementById('page_summary')
    editor = document.getElementById("new-summary-editor")

    if(textArea && !editor){
        var contentEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
            lineWrapping: true,
            mode: "markdown",
        });

        contentEditor.display.wrapper.id = "new-summary-editor"
    }
}

export {initialize}
```

Lastly here is one of the views which is having the issue:

```
<% @page_title = "New Page" %>

<div class="container form-container">
  <%= form_for @page, url: world_pages_path(params[:world_name]), html: {style: "width: 100%"} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', errors: flash[:errors] %> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :summary %>
      <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Create!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <% if params[:category] %>     
    <%= hidden_field_tag :category, params[:category] %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm pretty much at a loss for what could be causing this any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

After looking a bit through my browsers devtools, it is looking like the issue may be coming from the css not properly loading in my `editor.js` file, which is where I import the css files for code mirror.

edit-2:

When I remove the css import statement from the `editor.js` file, I get the same behavior in development, so I know for sure that that is the issue. If anyone knows the correct way to import styles from node modules that would be very helpful

Comment: Seems like a css issue. Perhaps you have a local css file that isn't being bundled (assuming you have a bundler) for deployment, or worse--because it will be harder to figure out, your bundler is changing the css load order.

Comment: Is there a way I could check if that is what's causing the issue? Could css be causing the x characters as well?

Comment: Are you familiar with any browser dev tools?  In Chrome, for example, you can look at the elements tab and see which classes have been applied, and which have been overridden.  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: Yes, from what I can see all the classes are correct and the same as they are when I run it locally. I have been combing through to see if there are any specific styles that may be causing it but haven't found any yet. Also, I am using firefox if that makes a difference

Comment: It looks like the elements that are positioned incorrectly mostly have inline styles.

Comment: Does the order of import statements matter?  Try putting the `codemirror.css` import before the `js`?

Comment: That did not seem to help the problem unfortunately. I am confident that particular statement is the issue though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone runs into something like this in the future, I was able to find an answer.

The issue was stemming from my misunderstanding of webpack.

I was directly importing the css from the node module into the `editor.js` file. I am still not a webpack expert so I couldn't say why this worked locally, but it didn't properly set up the css files to be compiled by webpack in production.

The fix was to instead create an `application.scss` file in `app/javascript/src`. It was in this file I added `@import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';`

After doing this I added `import '../src/application.scss'` to my `application.js` file so that webpack would know to compile the css.

Finally, I added `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` into my `application.html.erb` layout file which pulls in the css from the compiled files.